# Efficient way to reorder Vector Data (interpreated as 3D array)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on an application written in C++ which has to handle some data stored in a continuous memory space which are interpreted as a 3D array.
For efficient data processing, I have to change the data order in the memory.

So here is an example:
The original data are located in the memory and I have data access through a datapointer (`uint16_t*`) which is interpreted as 3D Array and has the following dimensions:
`xSize=4, ySize=4, zSize=3`
In the memory the data are located as the following: (d<sub>x,y,z</sub>)

d_*0,0,0* | d_*1,0,0* | d_*2,0,0* | d_*3,0,0* | d_*0,1,0* | d_*1,1,0* | d_*2,1,0* | d_*3,1,0* | .... | d_*3,0,2* | d_*3,1,2* | d_*3,2,2* | d_*3,3,2* |

Now I would like to have the data in the order z,y,x:

d_*0,0,0* | d_*0,0,1* | d_*0,0,2* | d_*0,1,0* | d_*0,1,1* | d_*0,1,2* | .... | d_*2,3,2* | d_*3,3,0* | d_*3,3,1* | d_*3,3,2* |

I did an implementation with the following loops:

```
for (uint32_t z = 0; z < zSize; z++) {
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < ySize; y++) {
        for (uint32_t x = 0; x < xSize; x++) {
            uint32_t readPos = z * xSize * ySize + y * xSize + x;
            uint32_t outPos = y * xSize * zSize + x * zSize + z;
            *(dataOutPtr + outPos) = *(dataInPtr + readPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to speed up this algorithm?
Is it possible to do some parts in a concurrency execution or does any one know another solution for the reordering of 3D data?

Comment: Which target platform? Is the size fixed?

Comment: Note: what you implement seems to be a (z,x,y) order and not a (z,y,x) order

Comment: since your loop does not look at the data concurrency is possible for sure here. You would just need to define which threads is responsible for which (x,y,z) tuple.

Comment: Since there is no possibility for races (assuming of course that `dataInPtr` and `dataOutPtr` do not refer to overlapping arrays) you can trivially parallelize this, for example with a `#pragma omp parallel for` in front of the first loop when using OpenMP.

Comment: Odd thought: Unless I misunderstood something, your data for one tensor is 4*4*3*2 = 96 bytes. Is there any benefit in attempting to parallelize such a small amount of computation? Assuming you have a big-enough array of these 3D tensors, I'd focus on parallelizing the loop over *those* elements instead.

Comment: @GPhilo I thought that too but it's prefaced with "example", so I would not assume this to be the real case.

Comment: Aha, I see, didn't think of it that way.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input. I have to check out the openMP stuff and I would do some performance test with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is necessarily a brutish algorithm. Either your loop has good cache locality in the source, or it has good cache locality in the destination, but not both. Ironically this is probably also why you are re-arranging the data, to get more appropriate cache locality for when you use it, but until you've actually done that re-arranging the original layout is going to slow you down.

Obviously you have to visit every element, and your innermost loop body is about as performant as it's going to get.

It may be possible to parallelize this — somebody else will have to explore that as I don't have knowledge there — but from a fundamental C++ perspective I reckon you're already doing the best you can. At least, unless you can preprocess or fix the source data, or unless you can live without the re-arranging altogether (e.g. if actually you don't care about cache locality and can therefore simply alter your indexing scheme as a façade).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the hints. It's truly a hard job to optimize this algorithm. First I tried to parallelize it with openMP - @Max Langhof Thanks for the hint! In my case, it reduced the time consumption from ~8s to ~6.5s (Yes there is a lot of data, x,y,z=1000+) Now in a next step, i optimized my algorithm that thy would work without the re-arrangment. Lightness Racess in Orbit thanks for this way of thinking! Of course the algorithm needs a bit more time, but this was also parallelized with openMP :) now the resulting time is ~4.5s! Wow cool, thank you all!